# Can I use GraphQL to extract data directly from CluedIn to PowerBI?

Tags: graphql, cluedin

Is it possible to use the CluedIn GraphQL endpoint to extract data out of CluedIn and export it to targets like PowerBI

Answer (score 1):

Yes, provided you use PULL and post the body with your GraphQL query.

For more examples of how this is done, check out CluedIn Postman Collection Here.
https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/26504/RVu8io2g#1076acee-b0fb-fa22-a263-44557c27b6b9

For additional information on CluedIn REST API

http://documentation.cluedin.net/docs/H-Consume/Rest-API/Rest%20API.html

You can then use the Advanced Query in Power BI and paste in

```
let
    vUrl = "https://app.<hostname>/api/api/graphql",
    vHeaders =[
            #"Method"="POST",
            #"Content-Type"="application/json",
            #"Authorization"="Bearer <insert token>"
        ],
    // Notice the quote escaping here
    vContent=Text.ToBinary("{""query"": ""{   search(query: \""*\"") { entries { name}  }}""}"),
    Source = Web.Contents(vUrl, [Headers=vHeaders, Content=vContent]),
    #"JSON" = Json.Document(Source)
in
     #"JSON"
```